# how to open base64 string as an email or download as email file in javascript

Tags: javascript, email, download, base64

I got an base64 string from back-end and From front end using JavaScript, I need to open it or download it into an email format file (.msg). I mean if it's possible to open directly on link click or download as an .msg file which on click open as as outlook document.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this. the following code will work for this:

```
<a download="data.msg" href="data:application/vnd.msoutlook;base64,0M8R4KGxGuEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA==">Download MSG file</a>
```

Thanks @Kristaps for your response.

Comment: No problem! Just one thing to note - the download property won't work in either IE or Edge (as it stands IE 11 will redirect you to an error page, and Edge will do nothing (as far as I can tell) - https://jsfiddle.net/5tcy3c26/ ). From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj710206(v=vs.85).aspx "For security reasons, data URIs are restricted to downloaded resources. Data URIs cannot be used for navigation, for scripting, or to populate frame or iframe elements."

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to use external libraries, then you can download the decoded string as a .msg file with https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/

```js
var contents = atob("c29tZXRoaW5nc29tZXRoaW5nc29tZXRoaW5n");
var blob = new Blob([contents], { type: "application/octet-stream" });
saveAs(blob, "mymessage.msg");
```

```html
<script src="https://rawgithub.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/master/FileSaver.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```